# Error in code - split string and return length of every word JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function getWordLengths(str) {

return str.split(' ').map(words => words.length)
}
```

my error is

```
AssertionError: expected [ 0 ] to deeply equal []
  + expected - actual

  -[
  -  0
  -]
  +[]

t('returns [] when passed an empty string', () => {
  expect(getWordLengths('')).to.eql([]);
});
it('returns an array containing the length of a single word', () => {
  expect(getWordLengths('woooo')).to.eql([5]);
});
it('returns the lengths when passed multiple words', () => {
  expect(getWordLengths('hello world')).to.eql([5, 5]);
});
```

Comment: test cases are ... it("returns [] when passed an empty string", () => {
    expect(getWordLengths("")).to.eql([]);
  });
  it("returns an array containing the length of a single word", () => {
    expect(getWordLengths("woooo")).to.eql([5]);
  });
  it("returns the lengths when passed multiple words", () => {
    expect(getWordLengths("hello world")).to.eql([5, 5]);
  });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```js
function getWordLengths(str) {
  return str.length > 0 ? str.split(' ').map(words => words.length) : [];
}

console.log( getWordLengths(""));
console.log( getWordLengths("Hi") );
console.log( getWordLengths("Hi there how are you") );
```

Comment: Hi Ivan with this i need to return [] when passed an empty string,that is where I am failing

Comment: @user12520391 (edited) there you go, this should work for you as you wanted.

Comment: :(     AssertionError: expected [ [] ] to deeply equal []
      + expected - actual

      -[
      -  []
      -]
      +[]

Comment: @user12520391 Sorry, I'm afraid I then don't fully understand you question. You said that an empty string needs to return `[]`, which it does, so I'm confused. Can you provide sample input that I can test against?

Comment: yes but now it is returning an array inside an array you see, test cases are at the top :)

Comment: @user12520391 Ok, I think I got it now. Should work perfect. Give it a try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
it("returns [] when passed an empty string", () => { expect(getWordLengths("")).to.eql([0]); });
```

.to.eql([0]) not ([])

Comment: HI Pranav how would that look in my code? sorry i'm not understanding

Comment: Hi, Your function returning a value [0] when an empty string '' given as input. You need to change the test case/code accordingly

Answer (score 0):

`str.split(' ')` returns an array with 1 item, where the length is 0.

```
"str".split(' ')  // ==>  [""].map(words => words.length) // ==> [0]
```

That is why your test case seems to be failing. You will have to either adjust the test cases or return an empty array when the `str` is empty.

```
expect(getWordLengths('')).to.eql([]);
```

to

```
expect(getWordLengths('')).to.eql([0]);
```

Also there is a possibility for false positives to creep up when you are compare objects directly. As each object will point to a different reference.

`[] === []` or `{} === {}` will return `false` ( I am pretty sure the sure testing library will account for this as they recursively checks for every field rather than the object reference  ). I would rather be more explicit in my test cases.

```
t('returns [0] when passed an empty string', () => {
  const computedArray = getWordLengths('');

  expect(computedArray.length).to.eql(1);

  expect(computedArray[1]).to.eql(0);
});
```

Comment: AssertionError: expected [ 0 ] to deeply equal []
      + expected - actual

      -[
      -  0
      -]
      +[]